# How to debug jq errors for parsing AWS price API

Tags: json, parsing, jq

I'm trying to parse out some of the AWS price API json results and noticed that I'm getting some errors on string and object validation, but can't figure out how to debug which object or string `jq` is choking on.

Could someone help point me in the right direction? I've tried changing `endswith` to `startswith` as well as contains, but all exhibit different errors, so I haven't been able to narrow the object in error (probably doesn't help the json response is 1.1M+ lines...)

Interestingly enough, using `endswith($type)` gets me the sku i'm looking for, but also returns `jq: jv.c:721: jv_string_value: Assertion 'jv_get_kind(j) == JV_KIND_STRING' failed.`

I tried looking at line 721 in *jv.c*, but I don't really know C, so I'm kinda stuck.

Thanks in advance.

SCRIPT:

```
#!/bin/bash
type="hs1.8xlarge"
curl -s -L -k https://pricing.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/offers/v1.0/aws/AmazonEC2/current/index.json | jq --arg type "$type" '.products[] | select(.attributes.instanceType | endswith($type)).sku'
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that for some of the products, there was no `instanceType` attribute.  I'm not sure what version of jq you were using but 1.5 gives the following error:

```
$ jq --arg type "$type" '.products[] | select(.attributes.instanceType | endswith($type)).sku' input.json
jq: error (at input.json:1128400): endswith() requires string inputs
```

That indicates that the value being compared wasn't a string.  `$type` is so the only thing left was the `instanceType` I don't know if there's an easy way to debug this sort of problem but I would usually start off by breaking the filter up each step of the way and inspect the result (and work on a local copy of the input).  Start with `.products[].attributes`, then `.products[].attributes.instanceType` and see if it looks like what I would expect.

To fix your particular problem, you just need to provide a string value for when there is no `instanceType`.

```
.products[] | select(.attributes.instanceType // "" | endswith($type)).sku
```

Comment: Old jq versions (I think it's 1.4 and below) used to panic when `startswith`/`endswith` were applied over non-string inputs; see https://github.com/stedolan/jq/issues/718

Answer (score 1):

It looks like an assumption your program is making about the input is invalid.

My guess is that you're using an older version of jq (perhaps jq 1.4), and that the assertion violation is being
triggered by one case in which .attributes.instanceType is not a string (most likely, a null).

So I'd suggest starting off by modifying your program to handle the case that .attributes.instanceType is not a string.

For example:

```
select( .attributes.instanceType | (type == "string" and endswith($type)) )
```

There is a convenient filter named `debug` for degugging, but in this case, it might be more trouble than it's worth.